# Institutionalised - Human Emotions

Tags: expressions, psychology

Most of us would be aware of the term **Institutionalised**, from the movie *The ShawShank Redemption.* They generally define it as in Wikipedia: [Institutional syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_syndrome).

While it refers to something in terms of geographical boundaries,

Is there any term to describe that emotion on a person? That feeling, that suffering, when someone very close to your heart is not near you. You cannot live without them.

Could anyone point out terms (*Love* excluded) describing such emotions?

Comment: Apparently, you have not understood the term *institutional syndrome* correctly.  A feeling " ... when someone very close to your heart is not near you ..." is **not** related to it in any way.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for the verb

> [***to miss***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/miss):   To feel the lack or loss of: *Do you miss your family?*

In a stronger vein, since you mention *cannot live without them*:

> [***to pine***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pine) : To wither or waste away from longing or grief: *pined away and died.*

Comment: **to pine** looks good for me, but i wouldnt die :P

Comment: Yes, it's often used figuratively, just as you used *can't live without them*

Comment: Pining for the fjords

Answer (score 0):

Longing. perhaps. Like "longing for her embrace"

Answer (score 0):

Isn't 'grief' the word you want?